# z-indexing and mouseclicks

Tags: css, positioning, z-index

I have a site layout that relies on alot of positioning on top of one another to create the desired visual effect. I have an image at the very bottom of the z-index pile and as a result the mouse cant recognise that its a link, is there any way around this apart from putting it up the z-index stack order?

Comment: You can post your code, but probably not.

Comment: What do you mean: "the mouse cant recognise that its a link".  Is it an image wrapped in an anchor?  Did you try adding an alert onclick directly on the image to see if it's actually being clicked?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided some code to look at or even try out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could position (absolute) a styled "a" tag so that it is over the area that you want to link. Ex:

```
a.specific{
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:200px;
  z-index:INFINITY! :);
}
```